# How to get CSS3 gradient to span the height of the entire page, not just the viewport?

Tags: html, css, background

I have a cross-browser CSS gradient, such as this:

```
#background {
    background: #1E5799; /* old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #002c5a 0%, #79d6f4 100%); /* firefox */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#002c5a), color-stop(100%,#79d6f4)); /* webkit */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#002c5a', endColorstr='#79d6f4',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
}
```

But I need it to span the height of the entire page, not just the viewport. In other words, I need to apply the style to an element that has the same height as the entire page, which would usually be `body` or `html`.

**Further complications:**
I'm also using the [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), which requires `html` and `body` to be set to 100% height. So applying the style to them results in only the viewport being filled.

I'm not even sure if what I'm asking is possible, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on Kyle's solution, as well as the other styles from the [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), here is the solution that finally worked:

```
.wrapper { min-height: 100%; height: auto !important; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto -250px;
 background: #1E5799; /* old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #002c5a 0%, #79d6f4 100%); /* firefox */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#002c5a), color-stop(100%,#79d6f4)); /* webkit */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#002c5a', endColorstr='#79d6f4',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */ } /* corresponds to height of #footer */

#body-wrapper {

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

With the following html:

```
<body>
<div id="body-wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Your website content here.</p>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is useful, It didn't worked for me because my wrapper for sticky footer is 1050px fixed width, so I just added your body wrapper div around it and put gradient on that.Same html form just added gradient to body-wrapper instead of wrapper.Thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
html body {
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

It will do the trick, the `min-height` property spans the total height even if the page is scrollable, but height property sets the height of active view-port as 100%.

This works cross browser!

Comment: Min-height on the html and body elements was the correct solution. Of course it won't work in IE6 but I'll live with that.

Answer (score 8):

Another option if you want the gradient to scale ONLY to your viewport but be maintained when you scroll. So instead of the gradient plotting the entire height of the document it remains relative only to whats visible. (Try it out you will see what Im saying)

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the entire content of the page in a background div, then set it to that. This way the wrapping div will fill up with all your content and the background will expand across the whole page.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="background-wrapper">
<!--all your content-->
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#background-wrapper {
    background: #1E5799; /* old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #002c5a 0%, #79d6f4 100%); /* firefox */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#002c5a), color-stop(100%,#79d6f4)); /* webkit */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#002c5a', endColorstr='#79d6f4',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

That should do it :)

Comment: +1 For sending me in the right direction, but in the end that didn't quite work.

Comment: Hey, glad it helped in some way :)

Answer (score 2):

you don't need a wrapper:

CSS:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    background: #603813; /* for non-css3 browsers */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#28abe2', endColorstr='#ffffff'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#28abe2), to(#ffffff)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #28abe2,  #ffffff); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

}
```

sample HTML:

```
<body>

 <div id="headerBG">
  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here
  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here 
  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here
  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here 
 </div>

 <div id="container"><!--start container-->
  <div id="content"<!--start content-->
   content goes here  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here
   content goes here  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here
   content goes here  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here
   content goes here  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here
   content goes here  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here
   content goes here  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here
   content goes here  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here
   content goes here  content goes here  content goes here  content goes here
  </div><!--end content-->
 </div><!--end container-->

</body>
```

The gradient won't show if you don't have any content inside your divs! :) Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

```
html, body {line-height:1.5;background:#23538a;

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #23538a 50%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(50%,#23538a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#23538a 50%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#23538a 50%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#23538a 50%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#23538a 50%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#23538a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}`
```

Comment: What is all the line-height malarkey?