# How to center a content DIV with a gradient wrapper background in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

It works for Firefox, Safari and Chrome but not IE. I tried given a `width` and then `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` Please help.

Here's the link
http://www.ellenselbiedesign.com/public/testing/index.html

Here's my CSS

```
* {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper { min-height: 100%; height: auto !important; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto -250px;
background: #aad3d9; /* old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #80BCC5 0%, #ffffff 100%); /* firefox */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#80BCC5), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* webkit */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#80BCC5', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */ } /* corresponds to height of #footer */

#body-wrapper {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#header {
width: 960px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#header img {
padding-top: 15px;
}

#header p{
color: #784f78;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:right;
margin-top: -33px;
line-height:90%
}
```

Comment: also never write width: 100% to divs. it does no good (ie you add padding and it breaks). it fills the avaiable space automaticly

Answer (score 1):

`<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657553/how-to-get-css3-gradient-to-span-the-height-of-the-entire-page-not-just-the-view -->`

Congratulations. Your IE is now in Quirks Mode. In Quirks Mode, IE acts like IE5.5, so it doesn't support `margin: 0 auto`. Try to remove comments before `<!DOCTYPE>` as comments before `<!DOCTYPE>` cause IE to use Quirks Mode.

Answer (score 0):

give text-align: center; to the parent element and set it back to left in the element itself

```
#body-wrapper { text-align: center }
.wrapper { text-align: left }
```